# Permission Denied: Missing or insufficient permissions on Android but working for ios Firestore

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to update my db in firestore in an android device but receiving error "Missing or insufficient permissions". If this is due to the rules, the same rule is working fine for update in iOS but not in android. Can someone point me out to a right rule. Below is the rule that i am using

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database


    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Code i am using to update the record

```
 db.collection("user").document(documentSnaapShotId).update(userData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
               sendUserToInitialPage();
           }
       }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               String error = e.getMessage();
               Toast.makeText(UpdateUserActivity.this, "Error:" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
```

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ksfq.png) is the code that i used to authenticate user and the code specific activity opens only if the user has been authenticated via phone. Now while debugging i found another issue where when i clicked on signout (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signout) it comes back to this page and throws the same error and app kills itself. I am guessing there is some issue with the way i am authenticating user. Any help please. Below is the whole code that i used for authenticating the user

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            mFirestore.collection("mydbexample").whereEqualTo("uid", uid).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                    if(e != null) {
                                        Toast.makeText(PhoneAuthActivity.this, "Error:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                    for(DocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                        docId = doc.getId();
                                        userFname = doc.getString("firstname");
                                        userLname = doc.getString("lastname");
                                        userCountry = doc.getString("country");
                                        userState = doc.getString("state");
                                        userCity = doc.getString("city");
                                        userArea = doc.getString("area");


                                        documentExists = (userFname!= null);

                                    }

                                    if(documentExists){

                                        sendUserToInitialPage();

                                    }

                                    else {

                                        sendUserToHome();
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                        } else {
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Incorrect Verification Code ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

private void sendUserToHome() {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(PhoneAuthActivity.this, GuestUserActivity.class);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();

    }

    private void sendUserToInitialPage() {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(PhoneAuthActivity.this, InitialPageActivity.class);

        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();

    }
```

Call Stack

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.virtualbloodbank, PID: 489
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at com.app.virtualbloodbank.PhoneAuthActivity$4$1.onEvent(PhoneAuthActivity.java:224)
        at com.app.virtualbloodbank.PhoneAuthActivity$4$1.onEvent(PhoneAuthActivity.java:217)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:1039)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that triggers the error message, and the exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: HI @FrankvanPuffelen i have updated the code above that i used to update the record in android studio.

Comment: "...and the exact error message and stack trace"

Comment: Also note that nothing in the code you shared shows that `if request.auth != null;` is met. A very simple way to do that is to `System.out.println(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` right before adding the data.

Comment: Updated further investigation inline @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That exception is due to you calling `for(DocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {` even when there is an error. You'll want to `return` in the `if(e != null) {` block as also shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: Also: the code in the second snippet accesses `mFirestore.collection("mydbexample")`, while the rules only grant access to `/users`.

Comment: I tried adding return but still showing up same issue.But i am debugging the issue and will update the thread, but regarding the second code snippet, i am sorry i accidentally inserted signup code instead of update code. 
Fixed the code now, can you comment your view now?
if it is regarding the rules, can you point me out on how to fix the rule please?

Comment: Update: adding return fixed the app crash issue. But still getting the original permission issue

Comment: @AdityaS How did you solve this permission issue? In my case android is working fine, ios showing permission issue. But the interesting part is, I can write the data from ios for the very first time. Second time not able to write. Any idea?